# How to assign the angle for each vertical resolution resolution cell in an image frame?

Tags: python, image-processing, video, opencv3.0, angle

I am trying to determine the different angles which belong to each vertical resolution cell (equally spaced by one pixel) in an image frame from the centre of said image.

Additionally, the resolution of my carmera is 720*960 and has a FOV of 149 degrees. The model is a GoPro 7 Black. Thus, in my case for an image ranging horizontally from 0 to 960 (as an index), i would like to find the angle belonging to each pixel from the middle of the image frame (so from the pixel with the index 480). I assume that the angle ranges from the middle (0 degrees) to reach the extreme right (74.5 degrees) and to the extreme left (-74.5 degrees). I assume that distortion and the fovial lens are factors that needs to be considered in this case.

Please do kindly let me know whether additional information is needed.

Thank you for your time, help and input.

Comment: You are just looking for the iFOV? Just divide the FOV by the number of pixels in a row. Most cameras have square pixels. If you are unsure, try to find the spec sheet.

Comment: @gnodab because of the high FOV maybe dividing the row won't give the accurate results. I suggest drawing some sort of radial cone with its top being at the bottom center of the image. That way we can truly get the angle of the pixel groups.